# Handsontable not opening in jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog, handsontable

I am using the Handsontable plugin and have numerous tables using this. They are showing fine on the parent page, but when I try and open a dialog with a table they don't show (only in IE). Here's a fiddle I put together proving the hiccup in IE http://jsfiddle.net/PAH5J/7/ ...the tables won't show at all. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="example" class="handsontable"></div>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p><div id="example2" class="handsontable"></div></p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the IE dev console, the handsontable and jquery.ui plugins loaded before jquery and were throwing errors based on the jquery dependency.  Rearranging the external resources to allow jquery to load first followed by jquery.ui then handsontable is the fix.

Comment: I see this working on the Fiddle, but I just can't crack it on my local machine.

Comment: Can you post your script tags to see what order your externals are in?

Comment: Sure, Start one up and let me know.